# Signup Form Fields are not rendering Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Here is my code
In Urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
def registeruser(request):
form = CustomUserCreationForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CustomUserCreationForm(request, POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(request, username=user.username,  password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
context = {'form' : form}
return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
urlpatterns = [
 path('signup/', registeruser, name='signup'), 
]
```

In forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Enter Username'})
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Enter Password'})
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Re-Enter Password'})
```

In Signup.html

```
  <form class="text-left clearfix" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in forms %}
          <div class="form-group">
          {{field}}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main text-center">Sign UP</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Result is
[Signup page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhJ8l.png)
I tried alot of settings but got no input field on signup page. It just render nothing.
Please help me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `for loop`, try just using [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/).

```
#view.py
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})

#signup
<form class="text-left clearfix" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-main text-center" value="Sign UP">
</form>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to add div tag with class around each input field. That's for design purpose of form.